# Not able to see scannable devices in . net maui app by using shiny bluetooth low energy libraryy

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, maui

i am developing maui app which can can scan bluetooth device around it .. but the problem the code neither show any error while building or while running but also show no devices as well in list..i am attaching my function as well

[code for scanning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obo5Q.png)
but it is keep skipping this code
[skipping this part of code for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4IZM.png)
due to which it is putting data in Results but idk why it keep skipping this code .. can anybody please help me thanks `your text`

i already tried to check the error with soe try and catch commands but its not working either idk why

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Code should never be posted as an image

Comment: Are you sure that there are scannable devices around you? How did you check?